# num++ in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var num = "1";
num = num+1; //Gives "11"
```

but

```
 var num = "1";
 num++; //Gives 2.
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `+` operator is also used for string concatenation.

```
var num = "1";
// The 1 is converted to a string then concatenated with "1" to make "11".
num = num+1;
```

Javascript is a weakly typed language, so it's more lenient about type conversions.

The `++` operator used in your case is the postfix increment operator which only operates on numbers, so it acts as you expect:

```
var num = "1";
// num is converted to a number then incremented.
num++;
```

To give a hint that addition should take place, subtract by zero:

```
var num = "1";
// Subtraction operates only on numbers, so it forces num to be converted to an
// actual number so we can properly add 1 to it
num = (num - 0) + 1;
```

Or use the unary `+` operator:

```
var num = "1";
// The unary + operator also forces num to be converted to an actual number
num = (+num) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because ++ is an numeric operation, so `num` is cast from string, then the operation takes place.

The `+` however can be both for numeric operands (add), as well as string operands (concatenation). So `1` is cast to string, then concatenated with `1`, which gives `11`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = "1";
num = num+1; //Gives "11"
```

First one is, + operator is string concatenation.  So you get the concatenation result.

```
 var num = "1";
 num++; //Gives 2.
```

Second one is, ++ operator is post increment operator.  So you get the added result.

If you wish to change the + operator for addition.  Use like this

```
 var num = "1";
 num = parseInt(num)+1; //Gives "2"
```

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.  So it return the integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are storing the string in **num** variable and it concatenates with num.
For storing number you have to remove quotes around 1 while storing it into a num variable.

var num = 1;
num = num + 1;

Now the result will be 2 instead of 1